# Redirect bots to static version of site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

Basically, I want to redirect bots from the regular site to the static version using the .htaccess file.

Here's the situation:
URLs in my site are in these formats:

```
http://example.com/?p=something
http://example.com/index.html?p=something
http://example.com/basic.php?p=something
```

and I want to use the .htaccess file to redirect bots that crawl one of the first 2 URLs into one like the third by either replacing index.html with basic.php or adding it if it's not present. The root should also become basic.php instead of index.html.

This is my current .htaccess file, which is wrong because it only works if the URL contains index.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|InfoSeek|msnbot|bingbot|Slurp|DuckDuckBot) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /basic.php [L,R]
```

If some kind soul could help me with this problem, it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://example.com/?p=something
http://example.com/index.html?p=something
```

To match either of these two you just need to make the pattern (ie. URL path) optional:

```
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ /basic.php [L,R]
```

Aside: From an SEO perspective this is a bit dubious. It could be perceived as "cloaking" - delivering different content to search engines than to users, which could have a negative effect. And search engines will obviously want to index your static site (the page being redirected to), not the site that "users" see.